# What do grave accents do/mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In as many expressions/definitions as possible please.

I'm writing a test function, where after the call fails, the function returns:

```
`this `fails with` "the state is propagated"`
```

(with the grave accents surrounding fails with ^ i don't know how to escape, sorry)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use them when something is a Kotlin keyword (like Java's `System.in`) but you need to call it. Then you can do

```
System.`in`
```

instead to make it work.

You can also use this in variables, functions, classes and any other identifiers. There is a small paragraph on this topic on [Kotlin's documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin).

Comment: Oh, so it's an escape kotlin<->java interoperability thing?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it is more than that.

You can use any class, function, variable, or **identifier** whose name contains spaces or symbols with grave accents.

```
class `Class name with spaces` {
    fun `method name with spaces, +, -`(`a parameter`: Int) {
        val `variable?!` = `a parameter` + 1
        println(`variable?!`.toString())
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val instance = `Class name with spaces`()
    instance.`method name with spaces, +, -`(100)
}
```

This is a compilable and working code:
[image: Result]

This is often used in testing, in order to make the test method names self-explanatory.

```
class OperationsUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun `addition should be commutative`() {
        ...
    }
}
```